# If $AA^{T}B=AA^{T}C$, then $A^{T}B=A^{T}C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is it true that for any suitable matrices $B, C$ if If $AA^{T}B=AA^{T}C$, then $A^{T}B=A^{T}C$?

I think yes, but my reasoning seems sloppy. In particular, I think if a vector belongs to the null space of $AA^{T}$, then it also belongs to the null space of $A^{T}$. Is this claim true. If the claim is true, the question is trivial. I think the claim is true because the dimensions of both $A$, $AA^{T}$ are same. Am I right? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If A is invertible then multiply by A inverse to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $A$ is a real matrix. Let $A^+$ be the pseudo inverse to $A$. Then:
$$
AA^TB=AA^TC\implies A^+AA^TB=A^+AA^TC.
$$
But $A^+AA^T=A^T$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), under "Identities") so the claim follows.

Comment: thats a good answer, but the existence of pseudoinverse is generally not covered in elmentary, or even, graduate linear algebra courses

Comment: @vidyarthi Sure. But you already supplied a more elementary solution. Plus, an answer serves more than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$ then we have

$$AA^T B = AA^T C$$
$$A^{-1} (A A^T B) = A^{-1} (A A^T C)$$

$$(A^{-1} A) A^T B = {(A^{-1} A) A^T C}$$

$$A^T B = A^T C$$

making use of the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.

I’ll leave it to someone else to answer your real question.

Comment: my answer above would also do well for non-invertible matrices

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem is true if the matrix $A$ is a real matrix, that is, consists of only real entries. This follows from the positive semi-definiteness of $AA^{T}$. We have 
$$AA^{T}x=0$$
$$\implies x^{T}AA^{T}x=0$$
$$\implies (A^{T}x)^{T}(A^{T}x)=0$$,
which, owing to the real nature of matrices, is true iff $A^{T}x=0$. Of course, we assume that $x$ is a real vector.